# SVG file imported as Vector in Android Studio not converted correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, adobe, vector-graphics

I have an image of a dinosaur that I have converted to an SVG from Adobe Illustrator (I did not create this image which may result to may lack of knowledge on what the issue is).
[image: Spinosaurus]

^ [Image is in PNG format because SVG cannot be uploaded, but both formats look identical]

However, whenever I upload this image into Android Studio using the "Configure Vector Asset" tool in the "Resource Manager" most of the image is transparent.
[image: Spinosaurus when imported into Android Studio]

^ [As you can see most of the image is transparent]

I have done extensive research on how to resolve the issue; however, I have not been able to resolve the issue. Although, I believe I have pin pointed the issue which is due to the fact that "The tool supports group elements for translation, scaling, and rotation. Groups do not support an opacity property" (from https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg).
[image: Issue as seen in Android Studio]
Unfortunately, even though I may be aware of what the problem is, I am unaware how to solve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Vector assets in Android are designed for simple artwork. They are not designed for arbitrary content. There are [libraries that support SVG](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/96) that you could use.